# Хочу запретить пользователям заполнять поля формы с отключенным js, для безопасной валидации, но я не понимаю как это реализовать. Подскажите пж

Tags: javascript, валидация, формы

Когда тебе нужно проверить валидность данных которые вводит пользователь, первое, что приходит на ум - это проверить с помощью js. Но вот зараза, js ведь можно отключит и тогда весь твой код проходит в пустую. Ответьте, кто знает ,что делать
в таких ситуациях.

Comment: Это не надо реализовывать. Наоборот, имеет смыл убедиться, что данные можно ввести даже без js.

Comment: Ничего не делать, валидируют только на сервере, в браузере разве что подсказка юзеру о некорректности данных.

Comment: как понять "для безопасной валидации"? Валидация -- это провека корректности введенных данных, а безопасность -- это соблюдение конфиденциальности определенных данных. Не знаю людей, которые бы отключали JS на типичном сайте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, валидация с помощью HTML и JS выполняет лишь визуальную функцию, создает удобный интерфейс взаимодействия с пользователем. Вам нужно отправлять данные формы на сервер с помощью POST/GET запросов и проверять их с помощью PHP.

Запрещать ничего нет смысла, в валидации на js вовсе нет необходимости, для этого достаточно атрибутов HTML `pattern` `maxlength` `minlenght`, а все визуальное сопровождение легко [сделать с помощью CSS](https://medium.com/russian/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-html-%D0%B8-css-c34c982d42a0).

Можно лишь дополнительно проверить все поля перед отправкой с помощью `validity.valid` и после этого посылать запрос на сервер. Но все равно, все это легко обойти, **основная проверка осуществляется на сервере**.

[Вот тут хорошая серия статей об этом.](https://schoolsw3.com/php/php_forms.php)

Чтобы запретить отправку формы без скрипта, можно поступить так:

1. запретить отправку формы в HTML:

`<form  id="form" onSubmit ='return false'>` - вернуть false при клике на submit

2. Добавить слушатель события в JS на кнопку submit:

   `button.addEventListener('click',submit)`

`function submit(){...тут вы осуществляете отправку на сервер}`

3. добавить: `<noscript><p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает скрипты!</p></noscript>`

Соответственно если отключен js форма не отправиться.

И как правильно отметили выше в комментариях, валидация - это лишь проверка правильности заполнения поля. А реальная опасность грозит вашей файловой системе на сервере, если вы имеете дело со злоумышленником,и не принимаете соответствующие меры, но не в случае с обычным пользователем.

Comment: разве автор упоминал PHP?

Comment: @MikhailIonkin Добавил про JS